# how to delete column in excel sheets using NodeJs or nodejs node modules

Tags: javascript, node.js, excel, npm

I have tried many methods its not working.

can you help me how to delete and add columns in excel sheet using node js

Answer (score -1):

found a solution [here](https://github.com/SheetJS/sheetjs/issues/352)!

```
// delete a specific row
function ec(r, c){
    return xlsx.utils.encode_cell({r:r,c:c});
}
function delete_row(ws, row_index){
    var variable = xlsx.utils.decode_range(ws["!ref"])
    for(var R = row_index; R < variable.e.r; ++R){
        for(var C = variable.s.c; C <= variable.e.c; ++C){
            ws[ec(R,C)] = ws[ec(R+1,C)];
        }
    }
    variable.e.r--
    ws['!ref'] = xlsx.utils.encode_range(variable.s, variable.e);
}
delete_row(shoppingList, 1)
```